# Grails war tomcat deployment is successful but could not access the project

Tags: grails, tomcat6

I am working on deploying grails war on Tomcat server in Unix. I generated the war thru STS. Tested the generated war  on tomcat 6.0 in windows box. This works fine.I deployed the same war in Unix machine, did not face any issues during server start up. But when i access the URL i am getting "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". No exceptions or errors displayed in logs.

I am using Grails 2.0.1 and tried deploying the war in Tomcat 7.0 and 6.0.

Comment: Have you deployed other war files to this same tomcat instance?

Comment: Can you paste the full URL you are trying here? You can mask or change the domain and app name

Comment: yes the other war files are woking fine.

Comment: URL i am accessing is http:\\<hostip>:8080\appName

Comment: Check out the logs of tomcat, have to be some error in the startup of the context.

Comment: Checked the logs, no errors at startup

Comment: Issue is fixed by hardcoding the production server url name in config.groovy